# Building QT 4.8.5 with Mingw64

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to build Qt4.8.5 with mingw64 (8.1.0) in windows 7. It successfully builds several libraries but gives an error when building xmlpatterns. I am not sure what the error is saying, Can someone tell me how to fix this error?

I configured qt using

```
configure -prefix "C:\Qt\qt_4.8.5_mingw64" -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake tools
```

Then ran make using,

```
mingw32-make install
```

After running for 30 mins it gave me the following error,

```
C:/Qt/4.8.5/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:503:25: warning: 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' writing to an object of non-trivially copyable type 'QVector
<QXmlNodeModelIndex>::Data' {aka 'struct QVectorTypedData<QXmlNodeModelIndex>'};
 use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
             ::memcpy(x.p, p, sizeOfTypedData() + (qMin(aalloc, d->alloc) -1) * sizeof(T));
 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../include/QtCore/qvector.h:1,
             from C:/Qt/4.8.5/src/corelib/io/qdebug.h:52,
             from ../../include/QtCore/qdebug.h:1,
             from ../../include/QtCore/QtDebug:1,
             from data/qanyuri_p.h:56,
             from api/qvariableloader.cpp:45:

C:/Qt/4.8.5/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:94:8: note: 'QVector<QXmlNodeModelIndex>
::Data' {aka 'struct QVectorTypedData<QXmlNodeModelIndex>'} declared here
  struct QVectorTypedData : private QVectorData
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Makefile.Debug:2640: tmp/obj/debug_shared/qvariableloader.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/4.8.5/src/xmlpatterns'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:46: debug-install] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/4.8.5/src/xmlpatterns'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:662: sub-xmlpatterns-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2

C:\Qt\4.8.5>
```

Comment: Although your compiler may be too new, you may want to try Qt-4.8.7. http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/

Comment: I am not sure but you may be able to select an older c++ standard than the default.

Comment: @drescherjm   I will try. Can you tell me what the error is saying? I don't get the error?

Comment: There is no error in the compilation output you posted, only a warning.

Comment: @Jaa-c        If you look at my last output lines it says there's an error in Makefile.Debug:2640, it doesn't complete the compilation

Comment: Yes, but you've not included the error in your output. It doesn't necessarily have to be last in the output. The warning is unrelated.